# Is this Quicksort Stable?

Tags: quicksort

I here that it is hard to make a stable quick-sort. However, my quick-sort seems stable.

```
quicksortBy _ []=[]
quicksortBy key (pivot:rest)=
    (quicksortBy key [little|little<-rest, key little < key pivot])
    ++ [pivot] ++
    (quicksortBy key [big|big<-rest, key big >= key pivot])
```

Then I do:

```
*Main> let items = [(4,0),(1,1),(10,2),(6,3),(4,4),(6,5), (1,6)]
*Main> quicksortBy fst items
[(1,1),(1,6),(4,0),(4,4),(6,3),(6,5),(10,2)]
```

By using the first item as the pivot, duplicates go to the right. Is this wrong, or is it that people don't use this since it is inefficient on sorted data. Or did I discover something new?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the algorithm you've described is stable, and is usually referred to as a "naive" quicksort. The problem with this algorithm is that it requires O(n) additional space to sort the array. More space-efficient versions of quicksort use in-place swaps to modify the array, which destroys stability, but reduces the space cost to O(log n) - effectively just the stack of recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your quicksort is stable is that (as you are in a functional language) it copies the elements (in order) into a new array or three at each step. That's fairly inefficient in both time and space, but (as you have found) it is stable. A more efficient quicksort using mutable arrays partitions the array in-place from the outsides in, which requires only one pass over the array at each level and only uses one extra element of storage, for swapping elements (and, with an integer array, can actually bypass even that using an xor swap).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is stable. 
Quicksort's inner loop is very efficient, so your algorithm may also be faster than other stable sorting algorithms like mergesort, though the probability is low I guess.
Drawback is, it consumes more space than mergesort (for storing indices as well).
And by looking at the comparison function, I guess it will perform very poor on arrays with many equivalent keys because they will require two branches each.

All in all, research freely and just use mergesort in application.